# Showing $\Omega = PP'$ implies $P^{-1}\Omega(P')^{-1} = I$, where $\Omega$

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

Similar as the title, how to prove that $\Omega = PP'$ implies $P^{-1}\Omega(P')^{-1} = I$, where $\Omega$ is a symmetric and positive definite matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by $P^{-1}$ on the left, then $(P^\prime)^{-1}$ on the right.